# How to access controls collection of dynamically loaded aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, webforms

Let's say I have two webforms, **A.aspx** and **B.aspx**, where B.aspx contains some simple web controls such as a textbox and a button.

**I'm trying to do the following:**

When A.aspx is requested,
I want to dynamically call and load B.aspx into memory and output details of all the controls contained in B.aspx.

Here is what I tried in the codebehind for A.aspx:

```
var compiledType = BuildManager.GetCompiledType("~/b.aspx");
if (compiledType != null)
{
  var pageB = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(compiledType);
}

foreach (var control in pageB.Controls)
{
    //output some details for each control, like it's name and type...
}
```

When I try the code above, the controls collection for **pageB** is always empty.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Some other important details:

- both webforms utilize a master page (so the web controls in b.aspx are actually placed within a "content" tag)
- I've also tried using [BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.createinstancefromvirtualpath.aspx). No luck.

Comment: Why you want to access control collection of executed page?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've done something like this, I've always had to use [Page.FindControl or Control.FindControl.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx)

Unfortunately, there is no recursive version of FindControl.  However, [this blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/) offers a FindControlRecursive function.  With it, you can iterate over all of the controls in a container (including, presumably, your PageB).

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id) 
{ 
    if (root.ID == id)
    { 
        return root; 
    } 

    foreach (Control c in root.Controls) 
    { 
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id); 
        if (t != null) 
        { 
            return t; 
        } 
    } 

    return null; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really think you should provide more background on what you're trying to do.  HttpServerUtility::Execute(String, TextWriter) will execute a page and write the result to the provided TextWriter object.  From there you can examine the contents of the page, and if the resulting HTML document is well-formed, you can even traverse its structure via the .NET XML APIs.

What's the reason you want to access the control collection of an executed page?